# deepcopy array in javascript is wrong

Tags: javascript, deep-copy

guy, i try to write a deepcopy function but it cant not work , but i cant not figure out the problem .

below is my script

```html
<script>      
        const obj = {
            name : 'ABC',
            age : 18,
            habbit : ['baseball', 'football', ['genshin', 'princess']],
            family : {
                son : 'sp',
                father:'fa'
            }
        }
        
        const newObj = {}
        function deepCopy(obj, newObj){
            for(k in obj){
                if(obj[k] instanceof Array){   
                    const arr = []
                    deepCopy(obj[k], arr)
                    newObj[k] = arr
                }else if(obj[k] instanceof Object){
                    const oo = {}
                    deepCopy(obj[k], oo)
                    newObj[k] = oo
                }else{             
                    newObj[k] = obj[k]
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        deepCopy(obj,newObj)
        console.log(newObj)
    </script>
```

and the reult is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsDgP.png)

habbit and family is wrong

i dnot know why im sorry. logic is stock

Comment: see: [structuredClone()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone)

Comment: The problem in your code is `for(k in obj){`. This declares a global variable that is mutated in the recursive calls. Use `for(const k in obj){` to fix your code. Always use strict mode to avoid such problems.

Answer (score -3):

do it like that easily

```
const obj = {
        name : 'ABC',
        age : 18,
        habbit : ['baseball', 'football', ['genshin', 'princess']],
        family : {
            son : 'sp',
            father:'fa'
        }
    }
  const copy =Object.assign({}, obj);
```

Comment: This does not create a **deep** copy.

Answer (score -4):

I think you can use

```js
const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original));
```

to clone Object and its nested Array/Object

Comment: This will only work for a limited class of source objects.